# Securely deploy an application with mySQL login data

Tags: c++, mysql, security

I am developing an application, which is using a mySQL database for login information's. For connecting to the database, I need the mySQL login data. I think, its a bad idea to distribute the mySQL login data with the app, so my question is, what is the common approach for that. I don't like to have a server running, which acts as a login server or whatever. So, how can you secure that login data in the application. Is it even possible, somehow? The user should not be able to read that login data out.
I read [Hiding MySQL Credentials in Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489360/hiding-mysql-credentials-in-application), but they suggest a server running, which I would like to avoid...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Could you read the credentials from an external file local to the server?  That way, you can distribute your application and include instructions to enter the correct credentials in a configuration file before running the application.

Comment: As I said, the connection is done from the app. There is no server (except the mySQL-server). I'm not sure that I got what you mean

Comment: Where will the app be deployed? It has to end up on a server (or someone's local machine) at some point. Having a local file on that machine is definitely the correct approach.

Comment: No. It is peer to peer